# Move the pointer in a bytearray as seek does for a BinaryIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, binaryfiles, bytebuffer

If I have a binary file, I can open it in mode `rb` and move the pointer with `.seek()`:

```
with open(fname, "rb") as fid:
    fid.seek(101)
```

But this is not possible with a `bytearray`:`bytearray(10).seek(1)`.

---

Does a `bytearray` which supports `seek` exist?

I have 2 almost identical code snippets reading data from a binary file/buffer that I would like to merge, one reading from a binary file and one from a byte array. The reading operation is done with `numpy`, with either `numpy.fromfile` or `numpy.frombuffer`. Both accept an argument `offset` to control the pointer position, but in a slightly different manner. `fromfile` defines the offset from the *current* position while `frombuffer` defines the offset from the beginning of the buffer.

Any idea on which object I could use instead of `bytearray` to be able to run the same reader code snippet on either an opened binary file `fid` or on a `bytearray-like` buffer?

Comment: There is `io.BytesIO`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks, that works with some adaptation since with BytesIO I need to use `.read()` with the size to read specified to move the pointer to the next location.

Comment: BytesIO actually supports seek.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do there is to subclass bytearray, and just add the `seek`, `tell`, `read` and `write` methods - it will work just like a bytearray for everything else, and can be used most places file-like objects are expected:

```
import os

class B(bytearray):
    def __init__(self, *args, size=None):
        if not args and size:
            args = (b"\x00" * size,)
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.cursor = 0
    def tell(self):
        return self.cursor
    def seek(self, position, from_where=os.SEEK_SET):
        if from_where == os.SEEK_SET:
            self.cursor = position
        elif from_where == os.SEEK_CUR:
            self.cursor += position
        elif from_where == os.SEEK_END:
            self.cursor = len(self) - position
        return self.cursor
    def read(self, amount):
        return self[self.cursor: self.cursor + amount]
    def write(self, data):
        self[self.cursor: self.cursor + (amount:=len(data))] = data
        return amount
```

And, using this in the interactive mode:

```
In [227]: b = B(4096)

In [228]: b.seek(100)
Out[228]: 100

In [229]: b.seek(100, os.SEEK_CUR)
Out[229]: 200

In [230]: b.write(b"Hello World!")
12

In [231]: b[200: 212].decode()
Out[231]: 'Hello World!'
```